# WhatsApp : how to stop calls from outside my contact list?

Tags: privacy, whatsapp

I keep receiving audio calls and video calls from people I don't know, and this makes easy for them to do stalking, cyberbullying, and harassement, the same kind of toxic actitudes that got me out of Facebook on the first place.

I'd like to limit audio and video calls to CONTACTS ONLY.

Is there an option inside WhatsApp configuration to stop these people the way I mentioned (allow only contacts)? Otherwise, I'll need to delete my <del>Yet Another Meta's Loser-Enabling App</del> WhatsApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhatsApp doesn't include an aption to "stop calls from outside from your contact list". They can be blocked only once you receive the first message or call from someone.

References

- [About blocking and reporting contacts](https://faq.whatsapp.com/414631957536067/?helpref=uf_share)
- [How to stay safe on WhatsApp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/1313491802751163/?helpref=uf_share)